# DbProviderFactories.GetFactory Method (DbConnection) missing

Tags: ado.net

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh323136%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) there is an overload of GetFactory(DbConnection) in .NET 4. However, I can't invoke it - fails at compile time saying:

```
error BC30518: Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'GetFactory' can be called with these arguments:
    'Public Shared Function GetFactory(providerRow As System.Data.DataRow) As System.Data.Common.DbProviderFactory': Value of type 'System.Data.Common.DbConnection' cannot be converted to 'System.Data.DataRow'.
    'Public Shared Function GetFactory(providerInvariantName As String) As System.Data.Common.DbProviderFactory': Value of type 'System.Data.Common.DbConnection' cannot be converted to 'String'.
```

Is there something wrong with my .NET FW or is it a typo in documentation?

Comment: +1 confirmed, the same for me with .NET 4.

Answer (score 0):

You can call the "GetFactory" method using the following solution: 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd0w4a2z%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

```
DbProviderFactory factory =
            DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(providerName);
```